# ExtJs 4.1 : How to send json data in the request body using Ext.Ajax.request()?

Tags: ajax, extjs, request, extjs4.1

I would like to send json data using `Ext.Ajax.request()` then access it in ASP.NET using `Request.InputStream` which is the content of the request body. I need a way to tell ExtJs to write the data in the request body as it is done while using an `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Specify `POST` method and just use the request's `jsonData` config:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'myUrl',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        requestParam: 'notInRequestBody'
    },
    jsonData: 'thisIsInRequestBody',
    success: function() {
        console.log('success');
    },
    failure: function() {
        console.log('woops');
    }
});
```

If you want a *record* written as JSON you can use a JSON writer like this also.

```
var writer = Ext.create('Ext.data.writer.Json'),
    record = Ext.getStore('SomeStoreID').first();

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'myUrl',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        requestParam: 'notInRequestBody'
    },
    jsonData: writer.getRecordData(record),
    success: function() {
        console.log('success');
    },
    failure: function() {
        console.log('woops');
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! The writer option is the icing on the cake!